# Query is being cached

Tags: mysql, laravel

Hi guys I'm having a strange problem, and I'm looking for help.

I'm using laravel 7, and one of my queries apparently is being cached or something, here's my code to explain:

Here's a very simple method in one of my controllers:

```
public function chartEstadosVoluntarios(){
    $estados = DB::table("voluntarios")
        ->selectRaw("estado, count(*) as total")
        ->whereNotNull('estado')
        ->groupBy("estado")
        ->get();

    return response()->json($estados,200);
}
```

If I hit the route on chrome the result is:

```
[
  {
    "estado": "Derivado al 147",
    "total": 2
  },
  {
    "estado": "Derivar a mesa de ayuda",
    "total": 7
  },
  {
    "estado": "Pendiente",
    "total": 3
  },
  {
    "estado": "Reasignar Adulto Mayor",
    "total": 50
  },
  {
    "estado": "Resolución logística 24hs",
    "total": 4
  },
  {
    "estado": "Resuelto",
    "total": 119
  }
]
```

But its wrong, its not the real result, here's a screen for the same query in MySQL Workbench:

[image]

I'm using the same user in workbench and laravel.
Another thing is that If I slightly modify the query, then i get the correct result, for example:

```
$estados = DB::table("voluntarios")
    ->selectRaw("estado, count(*) as total, 'test'")//adding 'test' to select
    ->whereNotNull('estado')
    ->groupBy("estado")
    ->get();
```

Then I hit the browser again, and the result is:

```
[
  {
    "estado": "Pendiente",
    "total": 9687,
    "test": "test"
  },
  {
    "estado": "Resuelto",
    "total": 16415,
    "test": "test"
  }
]
```

If i go back with the modifications i get the wrong results again.
So, I really don't understand what's happening, Any point of direction will be appreciated.

**EDIT, more info added from the answers:**

the toSql() method throws the same query (copy pasted from the browser):

```
"select estado, count(*) as total from `voluntarios` where `estado` is not null group by `estado`";
```

The toSql() method with 'test' in select:

```
"select estado, count(*) as total, 'test' from `voluntarios` where `estado` is not null group by `estado`"
```

Same results in Tinker:

[image]

Downgraded from laravel v7.10.3 to v7.6.2 (the one that i have before running composer update today), but the problem remains.

**EDIT 2**

Weird thing happens, I recently use another part of the system that edits the "estado" field of table "voluntarios" to see what happen, and now the query throws the correct results. it's like something has been unlocked after editing the table.
What could it be? I check before that the user had no open transactions.

Thank's in advance.

Comment: The laravel query builder sometimes might do something different then you might expect
You could do ->toSql() instead of ->get() to see what query it actually builds, and compare it with your query.

Also i always recommend to try starting out from Eloquent instead of DB::Table, however that should not be your issue for now.

Comment: Yes i already check the ->toSql() method, the query its fine, and already tried with Eloquent to, all the same wrong results.

Comment: Try in this way `->select( DB::raw("estado, count(*) as total") )`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ, same wrong results.

Comment: when you use selectRaw you don't need DB::raw, can you paste the toSql() output of both variants..., also the one with 'test'

Comment: @DannyEbbers added the two outputs to the question, i'm not using selectRaw and DB:raw, only selectRaw, the queries seems to be ok, it's really strange.

Comment: it is indeed very strange, i just checked a few projects and i am using selectRaw with counts pretty much, i usualy used them in subqueries, but with selectSub() but that shouldn't matter, i assume something totaly different is going op

Comment: Are you sure your controller is using the code you think it is using

Comment: Can you try pasting the query in artisan tinker?, then you are sure there is no browser cache, wrong routing etc...

Comment: run 'php artisan tinker' from console, and paste the query / you might need to add some use / import statements

Comment: @DannyEbbers same result in tinker, i updated the question. im working for the last 3 years with laravel and never happens something like this in any proyect, i recently updated composer and laravel update to the latest release, im going to downgrade to older 7.something release to see what happen.

Comment: Do you get what you expect if you add in SQL_NO_CACHE? `selectRaw("SQL_NO_CACHE estado, count(*) as total")`

Comment: @patricus no, same wrong result.

Comment: Is there any way you're somehow running the query against a different database than expected?

Comment: @patricus no, it's the same DB (an AWS RDS), and same user.

Comment: @patricus both throws same wrong result. thanks for the help.